# how do toggleClass in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I has example code html

```
<div class="new">
    <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="icon"></div>
          <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="icon"></div>
          <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
```

**updated:** I want when click to class icon in **wrapper first** toggle  class **list first** . And class  **list second** not change. Many thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: can you provide your jquery ?? it'll be better if you can provide fiddle along with the scenario

Comment: i tried use toggleClass and addClass for class content when click class icon. but it apply to all class content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.icon').click(function(){
$(this).next('.content').toggle('slow')



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new">
    <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="icon">QWE</div>
          <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="icon">QWE</div>
          <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Or [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: Thank you. can u help me? i updated question @guradio

Comment: `$(this).parent().next('.list').toggle('slow')` @xanka use this